# Printing the numbers from 1 to 100 and skipping the numbers divisible by 3 or 5. An indentation mistake returning two values

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, indentation

I want to print the numbers from 1 to 100 and skip the numbers divisible by 3 or 5. I made an indentation mistake I got two values. What is the logic?

Here is the code:

```py
i = 1
while i<=100:
    if not(i%3==0 or i%5==0):
        print(i,end="   ")
        i=i+1  ***indentation mistake***
```

Comment: `not(i%3==0 or i%5==0)` is the reason for getting 2 values. Since you start at the value 1, the value `1 % 3 == 0` will evaluate to `False`, similar to `1 % 5 == 0`, since both are unequal to 1. Then the `not` in front will make the statement `True`, leading to entering the loop. Which will increment `i=i+1` (also `i += 1` would work). Then we get `2` which also works, but for `3` the statement is `False`, since `3 % 3 == 0` is `True` (the `not` makes the whole statement `False`). And from that point onwards the `i = i + 1` is no longer executed and `i` is always `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thymen Already explained it very well in the comments, but basically `if not (i%3==0 or i%5==0):` will mean that if the number is divisible by either 3 or 5 then of course the code inside the `if` block will not be executed. This means that as soon as `i=3`, the `if` block will be skipped and the while loop will continue, without having incremented `i`, which leads to an infinite loop.

As a side note I would write this with a `continue` statement so it's clear what you're doing:

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    i += 1
    if not i % 3 or not i % 5:
        continue
    print(i, end="   ")
```

Comment: Why you did not put i % 3 or i % 5 ==0 but still code works without that also. How could this be?

Comment: The If statement returns condition of True or False, zero result returns False. Try x = not 1, and then print x.

Comment: Yes as @Susan said, if the value of `i % 3` is 0, then in a conditional statement it will return `False`